# Как написать Trait для контроллера UserController.php, который вернет информацию о сотруднике по его id

Tags: php, laravel

БД с таблицами users и users_roles я сообразил как создать но вот по поводу контролера и трейтов к нему в русском гугле я не нахожу

Comment: Собственно, вопрос - почему именно трейт? "контролера и трейтов к нему" - звучит, вообще, интересно.. не знал что трейты для контроллеров пишут.. 
Так-то, надо бы метод просто написать чтоб вытягивал юзера по id, всё..

Comment: Задание на вакансию, я сам уже 3 ночь не сплю ,  и решение так и не нашел, с вытягиванием с помощью метода я нашел но не думаю, что такой вариант устроит работодателя

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Трейтам в `php` без разницы какой глубокий смысл будет заложен в классе, к которому они применяются: будто контроллер, модель, и т.д. Применяют их для решения проблем одиночного наследования в `php`. При создании трейта для контроллера, по всей видимости, подчеркивается однообразность CRUD операций.

В Laravel метод, который детализирует сущность по `id`, называют `show`.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Traits;

trait Crud
{
  // Модель для работы с БД.
  protected $model;

  // Шаблон зачастую совпадает с именем таблицы.
  // В данном случае шаблоны модели `User`
  // будут располагаться в поддиректории `users`.
  protected $template;

  /**
   * Display the specified resource.
   *
   * @param  int  $id
   * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
   */
  protected function show(int $id)
  {
    // Получаем первый результат запроса, либо `404`.
    $entity = $this->model->findOrFail($id);

    // Динамически генерируем имя шаблона:
    // например, для файла `users/show.blade.php`
    return view($this->template.'.show', compact('entity'));
  }
}
```

Теперь данный трейт можно использовать в контроллере:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
  // Подключаем наш трейт.
  use Traits\Crud;

  // Используя паттерн внедрения зависимостей
  // Dependency Injection:
  public function __construct(User $model)
  {
    // а) определим текущую модель;
    $this->model = $model;

    // б) получим таблицу, связанную с моделью.
    $this->template = $model->getTable();
  }
}
```